# get the latest excel file and convert into html using php excel reader

Tags: php, html, excel

Can you help me with this? i don't know what to put or what to start to solve this.

i have an excel reader which is working fine, converting my excel into html and i have a code that detect the latest file in the directory

my problem is, what code should i put to display or get the latest excel file in the directory using php excel reader

here's the code that i have. Please help me

```
    <?php

class ReportViewer
{

    public $extension = array ( 'xlsx', 'xls', 'html', 'htm', 'csv' );

    public function getLatestReport($report)
    {
        $reports_directory = preg_split("/[\-]/", $report);

        //$latest_files = array();

        if (!ctype_alpha($report))
            $directory = $reports_directory[0].'/'.$reports_directory[1];
        else
            $directory = $reports_directory[0];

        $dir_contents = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);

        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_contents) as $filename => $file)
        {
            if (preg_match("/\.(" . implode("|", $this->extension) . ")*$/i", $file->getFileName()/*, $filename*/))
            {
                $latest_files[$file->getMTime()] = array($directory, $file->getFileName(), $file->getPath());
                //echo $file->getFileName() . "\n";
            }

        }

        krsort($latest_files);

        //print_r($latest_files);
       // print_r($timeMod);

        return $latest_files;
    }

}


?>

<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }        
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
    }        
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
    include 'reader.php';
    $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $lastest = new ReportViewer();
    ?>
    Sheet 1:<br/><br/>
    <table>
    <?php

    $excel->read('battery-report.xls');    
    $x=1;
    while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) {
      echo "\t<tr>\n";
      $y=1;
      while($y<=$excel->sheets[0]['numCols']) {
        $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
        echo "\t\t<td>$cell</td>\n";  
        $y++;
      }  
      echo "\t</tr>\n";
      $x++;
    }
    ?>    
    </table><br/>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are returning an array from `getLatestReport()` so use the first file in the list for your excel reader. if you can return the only required filename form `getLatestReport()` you can simply use `$excel->read($lastest->getLatestReport('battery-report.xls'));`

try this

```
<table>
<?php
$latestFiles=$lastest->getLatestReport('battery-report.xls');
$excel->read($latestFiles[0]);    
$x=1;
```

Comment: Thanks bansi, it's really a great help